# как представить сортировку в функцию

Tags: c, массивы, функции, динамические-массивы, пузырьковая-сортировка

Задача: отсортировать элементы нечетных строк матрицы А (6х7) в
порядке убывания, а четных – в порядке возрастания. Определить
функцию сортировки последовательности, направление сортировки
передавать параметром.
Написал сначала код без функций, подумав, что так будет легче, оставив их на последок.
Код без функций выглядит так:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h>
#define n 3
#define m 3
int main() {
    int a[n][m], tmp;
    printf("Заполните массив: ");
    for (int p = 0; p < n; p++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            printf("a[%d][%d] = ", p, j);
            scanf("%d", &a[p][j]);
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m - 1; j++) {
            for (int q = m - 2; q >= j; q--){
                if (i%2!=0){
                if (a[i][q] > a[i][q + 1]) {
                    int tmp = a[i][q];
                    a[i][q] = a[i][q + 1];
                    a[i][q + 1] = tmp;
                }
            }else{
                if (a[i][q] < a[i][q + 1]) {
                    int tmp = a[i][q+1];
                    a[i][q+1] = a[i][q];
                    a[i][q] = tmp;
                }
            }
        }
}
    }
    printf("Матрица имеет вид: \n");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            printf("%d\t", a[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

В итоге запутался в переписании основного цикла с сортировкой. А точнее, как обращаться к массиву внутри, а после сравнивать его и присваивать ему другое значение?
Код с моими функциями:

```
#define n 3
#define m 3
int a[n][m];
void input(int ncol, int mlines, int a[]) {
  int i, j;
  for(i = 0; i < mlines; i++){
    for (j = 0; j < ncol || (puts(""), 0); j++){
      printf("a[%d][%d] = ",i,j);
      scanf("%d",&a[i * ncol + j]);
    }
    }
}

void output(int ncol, int mlines, int a[]) {
  for(int i = 0; i < mlines; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < ncol || (puts(""), 0); j++){
      printf("%d\t",a[i*ncol+j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    }
}

void puzir_vpered(int ncol, int mlines, int a[]){
    int tmp=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < ncol; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < mlines-1; j++) {
        for(int q = mlines-2;q>=j;q--){
            if (a[i][q] > a[i][q + 1]) {
            int tmp = a[i][q];
            a[i][q] = a[i][q + 1];
            a[i][q + 1] = tmp;
            }
        }
    }
}
}

int main() {
int tmp, a[n][m];
input(n,m,&a[0][0]);
puzir_vpered(n,m,&a[0][0]);
output(n,m,&a[0][0]);
}
```

Функцию для четных строк решил не писать, да и не понял вовсе, как реализовать

> направление сортировки передавать параметром

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так устроит?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void sortLine(int * a, int m, int up)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < m - 1; j++)
        for (int q = m - 2; q >= j; q--)
            if( up ? a[q] > a[q + 1] : a[q] < a[q + 1])
            {
                int tmp = a[q];
                a[q] = a[q + 1];
                a[q + 1] = tmp;
            }
}

int main() {
#define n 7
#define m 7
    int a[n][m];
    printf("Заполните массив: ");
    for (int p = 0; p < n; p++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            printf("a[%d][%d] = ", p, j);
            scanf("%d", &a[p][j]);
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        sortLine(a[i],m,i%2);

    printf("Матрица имеет вид: \n");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            printf("%d\t", a[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: а возможно ли вообще дважды использовать функцию для одного двумерного массива так, чтобы они изменяли его частично? т.к. в самом задании указано, что направление сортировки указывать параметром

Comment: А что такое в `sortLine(a[i],m,i%2);` третий аргумент `i%2`, как не параметр, указывающий, как сортировать??!!